# Unable to get provider WorkManager is already initialized

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

Hello i can`t run my app and crash instantly and i got this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.bluechilli.flutteruploader.FlutterUploaderInitializer: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer? See WorkManager#initialize(Context, Configuration) or the class level Javadoc for more information.
```

Full Error Log:

```
    Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
E/AndroidRuntime(15636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15636): Process: com.hubmoe.box, PID: 15636
E/AndroidRuntime(15636): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.bluechilli.flutteruploader.FlutterUploaderInitializer: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer? See WorkManager#initialize(Context, Configuration) or the class level Javadoc for more information.
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7244)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer? See WorkManager#initialize(Context, Configuration) or the class level Javadoc for more information.
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.initialize(WorkManagerImpl.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at androidx.work.WorkManager.initialize(WorkManager.java:210)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at com.bluechilli.flutteruploader.FlutterUploaderInitializer.onCreate(FlutterUploaderInitializer.java:28)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239)
E/AndroidRuntime(15636):    ... 10 more
```

My build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hubmoe.box"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.hubmoe.box">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="HubmoeBox"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Deep linking -->
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="bedrive.vebto.com" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.bluechilli.flutteruploader.FlutterUploaderInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter-upload-init"
            android:exported="false">
            <!-- changes this number to configure the maximum number of concurrent tasks -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.bluechilli.flutterupload.MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS"
                android:value="3" />

            <!-- changes this number to configure connection timeout for the upload http request -->
            <meta-data android:name="com.bluechilli.flutteruploader.UPLOAD_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS" android:value="3600" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 11):

In AndroidManifest.xml:
Replace:

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:exported="false" />
```

with:

```
<!-- disable default Initializer -->
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="merge">
    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
</provider>
```

Comment: just incase anyone experiences `The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:node" associated with an element type "meta-data" is not bound.`. add this to your manifest ` xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`in `<manifest..`

Answer (score 3):

Huzaifa Saeed's answer doesn't work for me,

I change his answer to:

```xml
<provider
android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
android:exported="false"
android:enabled="false"
tools:node="merge">
<meta-data
    android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:value="androidx.startup"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:exported="false"/>
</provider>
```

This works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution works for me. The answer was to add enabled as "false" in both the provider and the meta-data tags